# Issue when trying to show exception: Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**I have below code**

```
try {
    $Role = $this->Get($obj->RoleID);
    if($Role == null) {
        return trans('Role.RoleNotFound');
    }
    $Role->Role = $obj->Role;
    $Role->save();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    dd($ex);
    return $ex;
}
```

**I am passing below data to this function**

```
{#157 ▼
  +"Role": "wsedde"
  +"RoleID": "31"
}
```

**What's the problem?**

As per the schema Role column has length = 2 and I by mistake passed length greater then 2. I have try catch applied but exception is not showing.

Can you tell why it does not go inside catch block?

Comment: can you show the content of Role before saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `catch (\Exception $ex)` (or alternatively, adding `use Exception;` to the top of the file right under the namespace declaration, with the other `use` statements). Laravel's namespacing likely means you're inadvertently attempting to `catch (App\Http\Controllers\Exception $ex)` here.

Comment: It seems it's truncating the chars but not creating the exception. Do you know why?

Comment: If you're using MySQL that's its default behavior. You can turn on strict mode. PostgreSQL will throw an exception if the data's too long. This should be handled via Laravel validation, not exceptions.